# Credential handles keeps going in process monitor

Tags: c#, windows, performance, security

Here I use the Microsoft Performance monitor to check the credentials handle for my c# application. I find the credentials handle keeps growing up. You can open performance monitor and add a "credentials handle" counter under "Security Per-Process Statistics". Will it cause handle leak? Will the handle be collected by GC? How can I use windbg or other tools to analyze this issue?

Here is my sample program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DBTest
{
    class DBTest2
    {
        class Program
        {
            [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "InconsistentlySynchronizedField")]
            static void Work(object data)
            {
                var dbConn = new SqlConnection("*********");
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(dbConn);
                dbConn.Open();

                string sqlQuery = "SELECT DBName = name FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE name = @DBName";

                using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbConn) { CommandTimeout = 300 })
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DBName", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = "***" });

                    command.ExecuteScalar();
                }

                dbConn.Close();
            }


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Timer tmr = new Timer(Work, "tick...", 1000 * 60 * 1, 30 * 1000);
                Console.ReadLine();
                tmr.Dispose();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your SqlConnection in a using block as well:

```
using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection("*********"))
{
}
```

Comment: It does not help, still goes up